# LoopBack4 generate uml model diagram

Tags: javascript, typescript, uml, loopback4

###### I'm thinking of generate a uml model for all models in my project. I tried the following packages but they didn't work for LoopBack4.

---

- [loopback-component-model-diagram](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-model-diagram/)
- [loopback-component-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-explorer/)

I added *mountPath* to `component-config.json` file. But it did not work!

I only see the *swagger page*, I can't see any **uml model** generated page.

```
{ "mountPath": "/modeldiagram" }
```

What should I do other than add *mountpath* or do you know of any package that generates **uml model** for the models?